# Window-Based Application: Which one?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have just downloaded the brand new cocos2d 1.01, and I am trying to create a new iphone/iPad project. I was reading online to go to /Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates/Application and make a copy of the Window-Based application.

Problem is, since that online-tutorial was written, there are a total of 6 options, including a Window-based iPad, a Window-based iPhone, and a Window-based Universal folder within that folder. If I am trying to develop an iPhone & iPad game that can serve as a universal app on the Store with cocos2d and Xcode, what option should I copy-paste onto the desktop (and then move forward with copying in the cocos2d files)?

I have tried searching this, but all the answers are old, (some as old as cocos2d .72!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the 'install-templates.sh' which is included with cocos2d. It will setup the xcode templates. Then you can just choose the cocos2d templates when creating a new project. By default(atleast on my machine) the device is set to iPhone. To change that just change the device or Targeted Device Family under the build settings for the project and target.

Comment: I clicked on install_templates.sh to run it, and all it did was open up the install-templates.sh file. The code is largely in red, which I think means it's having problems reading it.

I placed the cocos2d-iphone-1.01 folder in the /Developer/Library folder.

Should I have placed the folder elsewhere?

Comment: @GPP Some part of the text is probably red because you are viewing the file with an editor. If you run the script from the terminal, it will place the templates for you. I haven't touched the template folder except running the script. Take a look at the 'README.md'file
it explains how to run the script.